# Make a program admin-only in Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I had a question about Windows 10 - is it possible to make cmd.exe, as well as running **any** *.bat, .cmd* files admin-only?

Optimally I would like to do this without any additional software.

Comment: The question clearly is nothing to do with the running of a batch script as administrator. The OP is asking to restrict all cmd.exe and .bat/.cmd to either the administrators group or to the administrator. As such it is not a question for this site.

Comment: Requiring cmd.exe to have admin access is a question for Superuser, you're right; but the "as well as running any bat/cmd files admin-only" bit can be answered by the question I linked.

Comment: I think the question of whether or not this question belongs on this site can be argued both ways.  I can see both sides to it.

Comment: Is this for a stand-alone Windows 10, or is the machine joined to a network of computers, such as Active Directory?

Comment: You add a manifest to your program that says `requestedExecutionLevel\level="requireAdministrator"`

Comment: Group policy, or the equivalent registry keys, e.g., [see this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-disable-command-prompt-windows).  Keep in mind that any such restriction is easy for a knowledgeable user to bypass.  The only comprehensive solution is an application whitelist, so that the user can only run executables you've whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to restrict`.bat` `.cmd` and `cmd.exe`. Here are a couple links on how to do so...

[How to disable the Windows Command Prompt & .cmd Via Group Policy](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001005.htm)

[Microsoft Forum On Securing Batch Files](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-lock-the-batch-file/40ba3012-df88-4b9d-be2c-bd1e3bfc7176)